# How can you pass the state of a variable to a sub-form?

Tags: c#, winforms, subform

I have a form which contains a bool `unitConnected`. How can I pass the state of this boolean to a sub-form which I create and open at the press of a button?

Main form code:

```
// Global variable
public bool unitConnected = false;

private void buttonOpenSubForm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    unitConnected = true;

    SubForm subForm= new SubForm();

    if (subForm.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

Sub-form code:

```
private MainForm mainForm = new();

public SubForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void SubForm_load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (mainForm.unitConnected) // Do something
}
```

Comment: "So, is there a way to reference the existing MainForm object, in which unitConnected has been changed?" - yes, add a parameter to the constructor, then call `new SubForm(this)`. Or if you only need to know about `unitConnected`, pass that into the constructor instead.

Comment: Remove `private MainForm mainForm = new();`: that's a new instance of MainForm, not related to the one that set `unitConnected = true;` -- You can pass the instance of the calling Form to a Constructor of SubForm, or pass the **current** value directly (unless you want to make `unitConnected` static, different story, other potential issues lurking)

Comment: @JonSkeet - Thank you, that worked. I passed a reference to the main form when constructing the subform `public SubForm(MainForm mainForm){ InitializeComponent(); this.mainForm = mainForm; }` and then called it with `new SubForm(this)` as you said.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Answer by @Jon Skeet (in comments):
"You can add a parameter to the constructor, then call `new SubForm(this)`. Or if you only need to know about unitConnected, pass that into the constructor instead."

Sub-form:

```
private MainForm mainForm = new();

public SubForm(Form1 mainForm)
{
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

Main form:

```
public bool unitConnected = false;

private void buttonOpenSubForm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    unitConnected = true;

    SubForm subForm= new SubForm(this);

    if (subForm.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

As I understand it, you want to create something like a **MessageBox** where you will open a form containing specific information and in the end you will choose "OK" or "Cancel". If this is your intention, you should follow the following steps.

**Step 1:**

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     SubForm sub = new SubForm();
     if (sub.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK)
     {
        //Your Code
     }
  }
```

**Step 2:**

In the "SubForm" model, add a button and set the DialogResult property of this button to any value I choose as "Ok".

Note that if you want to receive any values from the "SubForm" model, set up a mediator **class** of type "static" and enter the properties and functions you need in order to access these values from anywhere in a excellent manner.